# How do I use postMessage() in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, rest, postmessage

Is it possible to use the `postMessage()` method in Javascript to do cross-domain `POST`, `GET`, `PUT`, etc. calls? If so, how? And how do I pass headers and data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a two way implementation, meaning that the page you want to call needs to have a callback that listens to such a message and give an appropriate response. You can't simply use it as a swap replacement for AJAX. The best method for that is to use a server-side proxy.

[See this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage) for an explanation of how `postMessage` works.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible.

There is a nice demo of what exactly you want, [here](http://html5demos.com/postmessage2)

```
document.getElementById("iframe").contentWindow.postMessage(
        document.getElementById("message").value,
        "http://anotherdomain.com"
);
```

handled on the second side with

```
window.onmessage = function(e){
  if ( e.origin !== "http://html5demos.com" ) {
    return;
  }

  document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = e.origin + " said: " + e.data;
};
```