# Accessing the document of a cross domain iframe using an extension in Chrome 45.0.2454.101

Tags: google-chrome-extension, cross-domain

I am using a content script in a Chrome extension to access a document in a cross domain iframe, using this code:

```
document.querySelector('iframe').contentWindow.document
```

This worked fine until I upgraded to the latest version of Google Chrome (45.0.2454.101 64-bit), which reports the following security error when accessing the iframe:

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin
"http://www.miercn.com" from accessing a frame with origin
"http://pos.baidu.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.
```

What changed in this version of Chrome and how to resolve this problem?

My Chrome version:

> Google Chrome 45.0.2454.101 (正式版本) （64 位）
>   修订版本  3b3c00f2d95c45cca18ab944acced413fb759311-refs/branch-heads/2454@{#502}
>   操作系统  Mac OS X  Blink 537.36
>   (@3b3c00f2d95c45cca18ab944acced413fb759311) JavaScript    V8 4.5.103.35
>   Flash 19.0.0.185 用户代理 Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4)
>   AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.101
>   Safari/537.36 命令行 /Applications/Google
>   Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome --enable-avfoundation
>   --enable-avfoundation --flag-switches-begin --flag-switches-end

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You will have to use [cross-domain messaging](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8172654/3959875) via [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage).

And in order for your content script on the main page to communicate with the content script injected into the iframe, the content script should be injected in [all frames](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#all_frames):

```js
"content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["content.js"],
    "all_frames": true
}],
```

Comment: Thx, you saved my life! "all_frames" does the trick.