# Access isolated iframe chrome extension of a cross origin domain

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I build a chrome extension as isolated iframe, which gets injected to a website via the `content.js` script. The user can access the extension via a shortcut. So if the user enters the shortcut the iframe pops up. Inside the iframe is an input field that I want to focus when the user enters the shortcut.

My first idea was to do something like this:

```
document.querySelector('iframe').contentWindow.document.getElementByid('#myInput').focus()
```

But this did lead to the following error:

> Blocked a frame with origin samplepage.com from accessing a
> cross-origin frame. at chrome-extension://sampleapp/content.js:38:64

Then I have [hereby](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32819079/9843082) found out that I need to set `all_frames` to true inside the `content_scripts` and tried [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25098153/9843082) for the same origin policy. So I put this inside `content.js`

```
const frame = document.getElementById('your-frame-id');
frame.contentWindow.postMessage(/*any variable or object here*/, 'http://your-second-site.com');
```

and this inside my `app.js` of the iframe

```
window.addEventListener('message', event => {
    // IMPORTANT: check the origin of the data! 
    if (event.origin.startsWith('http://your-first-site.com')) { 
        // The data was sent from your site.
        // Data sent with postMessage is stored in event.data:
        console.log(event.data); 
    } else {
        // The data was NOT sent from your site! 
        // Be careful! Do not use it. This else branch is
        // here just for clarity, you usually shouldn't need it.
        return; 
    } 
});
```

But all of this didn't work neither.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like all you need is to autofocus the input element once your iframe itself becomes focused.

content.js:

```js
const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.src = chrome.runtime.getURL('iframe.html');
iframe.style.cssText = '...............';
iframe.onload = () => iframe.focus();
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

iframe.js:

```js
window.addEventListener('focus', () => {
  document.getElementById('myInput').focus();
});
```

Note that `all_frames` isn't necessary and won't work here because the iframe doesn't have web content, it's an extension page shown inside so content scripts won't autorun there.